# TCP source and destination ports switch

Tags: port, tcpip, sniffing

Why do i see source and destination ports switching with each other in a packet capturing application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing each side of the conversation in each successive line of the capture. Example:

10.1.1.1:25613 > 10.1.1.2:80

10.1.1.2:80 > 10.1.1.1:25613